# How many domains does single Enterprise Edition support?

Tags: magento-enterprise

Is there a restriction on number of domain names per store?

I am aware that I can create multiple website inside a single Magento Enterprise Licence.

Lets say I have 10 odd number of individual domains purchased from different registras.

Can I switch them individually to my Magento Websites? Is there any restriction for number of domains ?

Comment: I think you should post your question on your Magento EE portal.

Answer (score 1):

no, Magento supports `n` number of sites both in CE, EE editions

but be careful to use all the stores in a single system, admin functionality will be complex and also it will increase resource requirements